# How to get IPN response in reccuring payment in eache payment successs after each cycle

Tags: php, curl, paypal, payment-gateway

Step 1. request with SetExpressCheckout

if get success then redirect to paypal

Step 2. curl request with method DoExpressCheckoutPayment With notify url

( getting response only one time )

step 3 if get success response then curl request with method CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile

is my process flow right to create an intent payment and make a recurring profile ?

and my problem is that i not getting any IPN response when, payment automatically after 1 day. How to fix this.

Comment: Do you have an IPN address in your PayPal account?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Login in to http://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts

Create an Business (merchant account) account and login to http://sandbox.paypal.com/ with your

Business (merchant account) and password and click on profile then click **Instant Payment Notification preferences and set your ipn url